# SP2013 SP-Hosted O365 App -- Update List Won't Work

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365

I was wondering if anyone can see something wrong with this update function? I have been fighting with this since Friday afternoon -- I have returned and alerted the correct value but the record doesn't change.

```
this.updatePrefs = function (scope) {
    /*return scope.current_user.nTaskClosed;*/
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);
    var web = appContextSite.get_web();
    context.load(web);
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('itiUsers');

    var listItem = list.getItemById(scope.current_user.ID);

    listItem.set_item('Division', scope.current_user.Division);
    listItem.set_item('Manager', scope.current_user.Manager);
    listItem.set_item('Role', scope.current_user.Role);
    listItem.set_item('rtaEmail', scope.current_user.rtaEmail);
    listItem.set_item('rtaReport', scope.current_user.rtaReport);
    listItem.set_item('rtaSAP', scope.current_user.rtaSAP);
    listItem.set_item('rtaWeb', scope.current_user.rtaWeb);
    listItem.set_item('ResourceFunction', scope.current_user.ResourceFunction);
    listItem.set_item('nTaskCreated', scope.current_user.nTaskCreated);
    listItem.set_item('nTaskUpdated', scope.current_user.nTaskUpdated);
    listItem.set_item('nTaskClosed', scope.current_user.nTaskClosed);
    listItem.set_item('newUser', 0);
    listItem.update();

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
        }),
        Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
            deferred.reject('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        })
    );
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [deferred.promise() method](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) returns a Deferred’s Promise object, the line:

```
return deferred.promise;
```

contains a typo and have to be replaced with:

```
return deferred.promise();
```

Comment: OMG! Three days and I missed that it was a method and not a property. It wasn't a type but just a stupid error. Thanks!!!

Comment: Yep, I also noticed it not at once :)  Glad this helped you!